# How to write custom predict function for classification model in R?

Tags: r, h2o

I am trying to use the `flashlight` package with the `h2o` package. An example of doing this on a regression model can be found [here](https://rdrr.io/github/mayer79/flashlight/f/backlog/flashlight_h2o.Rmd). However, I am trying to make it work for a classification model... to achieve this I was following the example given in the link. `flashlight` will work with `h2o` if you provide your own custom predict function. However, the predict function that is in the example below does not work for classification.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
library(flashlight)
library(h2o)

h2o.init()
h2o.no_progress()

iris_hf <- as.h2o(iris)
iris_dl <- h2o.deeplearning(x = 1:4, y = "Species", training_frame = iris_hf, seed=123456)

pred_fun <- function(mod, X) as.vector(unlist(h2o.predict(mod, as.h2o(X))))
fl_NN <- flashlight(model = iris_dl, data = iris, y = "Species", label = "NN", 
                    predict_function = pred_fun)
```

But when I try and check the importance or interactions, I get an error.... for example:

```
light_interaction(fl_NN, type = "H",
              pairwise = TRUE)
```

Throws back the error:

> Error: Assigned data `predict(x, data = X[, cols, drop = FALSE])` must
> be compatible with existing data. Existing data has 22500 rows.
> Assigned data has 90000 rows. ℹ Only vectors of size 1 are recycled.

I need to change the predict function somehow to make it work... but I have had no success yet... any suggestion as to how I could change the predict function to work?

EDIT UPDATE: So, I found a custom predict function that works with the `light_interaction` function. That is:

```
pred_fun <- function(mod, X) as.vector(unlist(h2o.predict(mod, as.h2o(X))[,2]))
```

Where the above is indexed for the specific category. However, The above doesn't work for calculating the importance. For example:

```
light_importance(fl_NN)
```

Gives the error:

```
Warning messages: 
1: In Ops.factor(actual, predicted) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors 
2: In Ops.factor(actual, predicted) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors
3: In Ops.factor(actual, predicted) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors
4: In Ops.factor(actual, predicted) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors
5: In Ops.factor(actual, predicted) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors
```

So, Im still trying to figure this out!?

Comment: You prediction function is wrong, which you can see by simply executing it on the training data `pred_fun(iris_dl, iris_hf)`